# Variable Substitution

Tags: oracle, toad

I am working in TOAD for Oracle and am trying to use variable substitution in my coding.

I have been able to get variable substitution to work in the code body pressing F5:

```
Define Value = '1.5'
Create table XX_DELETEMEEE as Select 
percent * To_Number('&&Value') Test
from Source_Table;
```

I have been unable to make the variable work in the same way for text as table names or column names:

```
Define PROJECT = 'P747'
Create table XX_DELETEMEEE as Select 
percent (To_CHAR('&&Project'))
from Source_Table;
```

The error for this code has 'percent' as an invalid identifier.

```
Define PROJECT = 'P747';
Create table &&Project||_MU as Select 
percent
from Source_Table;
```

The error for this code has table name as an invalid option.

Any ideas on how to make this work while not straying to far in methodology?

Comment: Is it possible to tell Toad to display the text after the substitution? 'sqlplus' has the 'SET VERIFY ON' directive to achieve this.What is the effect of ´Define PROJECT = 'P747'`. is the content of PROJECT `'P747'´ or ´P747´ ?  If ´percent´ is a column nam then `percent (...)` is a strange construct.

Comment: Everything that is shown are examples... percent could be any column name, maybe percent was a bad choice... could be Column1. The value after the '=' is meant to be what is directly placed as the substitution. What would displaying the text after substitution accomplish? I have never used 'set verify on'

Comment: percent (....) was meant to just rename the column name.... percent could be a case statement or something.

Comment: 1) 'What would displaying the text after substitution accomplish?'  We would see what text is sent to the server.  So what do your statements look like after substitution?

Comment: old: CREATE TABLE &&PROJECT||_MU as Select 
percent
from Source_Table;
new: CREATE TABLE P747||_MU as Select 
percent
from Source_Table

Comment: old: Create table XX_DELETEMEEE as Select 
percent (To_CHAR('&&Project'))
from source_table
new: Create table XX_DELETEMEEE as Select 
percent (To_CHAR('P747'))
from source_table

Comment: I figured out the column error... now I just have the table name variable issue... the solution was to remove all the junk around the variable call... (TO_CHAR('&&Project')) became &&project.... this worked fine

Comment: 2) ' percent could be a case statement or something'  It is not the name `percent` that confuses me. You place an sql expression `(...)` after a column name. I don't know such a construct. Here is the syntax of the select list: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2126854

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define/& is a simple text substitution mechanism that does not know anything about sql. And sql and the Oracle Database server do not know anything about the text processing mechanism. So the text that results from the 'define/&'substitutuin must be valid sql statement. Otherwise you get an error.

```
 CREATE TABLE P747||_MU as Select percent from Source_Table
```

is not a valid sql statement.

```
 CREATE TABLE P747_MU as Select percent from Source_Table
```

is  the valid statement, an so

```
Define PROJECT = 'P747';
Create table &&Project._MU as Select 
percent
from Source_Table;
```

Avariable name like &&Project must be followed by a whitespace or and end of file or by a dot (.). The dot is removed after variable substitution.

```
Define PROJECT = 'P747';
Create table &&Project_MU as Select
percent
from Source_Table;
```

will not work, because the variable is &&Project_MU and not &&Project.

you mix up simple text substituion in the Toad editor ( 'define/&)  with sql string functions (to_char, ||). That are different things.

Comment: So would Create Table &&Project_XXXXXX work with Project = 'Some Text string'? XXXXX being any other text I want to tac on?

Comment: you need the dot to delimit the variable name. I edited my post.